# How is my code producing this crash: [NSConcreteData count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I am getting this crash showing up in BugSense:

```
-[NSConcreteData count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e57f10 - NSInvalidArgumentException
```

in this code:

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)applyFilters:(NSMutableArray *)theItems fromFilter:(NSDictionary *)filters
{    
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:theItems];

    if ([[filters allKeys] count] > 0)
    {
        NSMutableArray *tempFilteredItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSString *key in [filters allKeys])
        {
            NSMutableString *convertedKey = [NSMutableString stringWithString:key];

            [convertedKey replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                                       withString:@"_" 
                                          options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [convertedKey length])];

            NSArray *tempFilterAttributes = [NSArray arrayWithArray:filters[key]];

            for (NSDictionary *item in items) 
            {   
                if (![[item[convertedKey] componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"] firstObjectCommonWithArray:tempFilterAttributes])
                {
                    if (![tempFilteredItems containsObject:item])
                    {
                        [tempFilteredItems addObject:item];
                    }
                }
            }

            [items removeObjectsInArray:tempFilteredItems];
            [tempFilteredItems removeAllObjects];
        }        
    }

    return items;
}
```

Why/how is this happening?

Stack trace is:

```
    CoreFoundation  <redacted> + 130    
1   libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 38   
2   CoreFoundation  <redacted> + 202    
3   CoreFoundation  <redacted> + 706    
4   CoreFoundation  _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24  
5   CoreFoundation  <redacted> + 28 
6   Video Games +[Helper applyFilters:fromFilter:] (Helper.m:2862)  
7   Video Games -[WishlistViewController loadUp] (WishlistViewController.m:409) + 29303 
8   Video Games -[WishlistViewController viewWillAppear:] (WishlistViewController.m:363) + 27955    
9   UIKit   <redacted> + 374    
10  UIKit   <redacted> + 612    
11  UIKit   <redacted> + 572    
12  UIKit   <redacted> + 44 
13  UIKit   <redacted> + 184    
14  UIKit   <redacted> + 380    
15  QuartzCore  <redacted> + 142    
16  QuartzCore  <redacted> + 350    
17  QuartzCore  <redacted> + 16 
18  QuartzCore  <redacted> + 228    
19  QuartzCore  <redacted> + 314    
20  UIKit   <redacted> + 126    
21  CoreFoundation  <redacted> + 20 
22  CoreFoundation  <redacted> + 286    
23  CoreFoundation  <redacted> + 738    
24  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524  
25  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106    
26  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 138   
27  UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1136    
28  Video Games main (main.m:16) + 888911   
29  libdyld.dylib   <redacted> + 2
```

Comment: 1. Is your code using ARC?  2. Can you provide a complete stack trace?

Comment: If `filters` is `nil`, your conditional is effectively `if (0 > 0)`, which is false, so your loop will never start.

Comment: You can add an Exception breakpoint too, so you will know what line causes the exception.

Comment: I can't repro the crash... I am only getting in through BugSense from very few random crashes out of 1000's of users.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with the code that you provided. The error messages says that the message `count` was sent to the **class** `NSConcreteData`, which is essentially the same as `NSData`, and such a class method does not exist.
I suggest that you set an **exception breakpoint** (in Xcode select left the breakpoint navigator, click `+` left bottom, and select *add exception breakpoint*).
When you execute the app, it will stop at the faulty instruction.

**EDIT** (due to the stack trace you provided now):
The stack trace indeed says that your method `applyFilters:fromFilter:` is responsible for the crash. The only place where the message `count` is sent in this method, is the statement `[[filters allKeys] count]`. It looks then that `count` is sent to an `NSConcreteData` object, and not to an `NSArray` object as you might have expected. One reason could be that the argument `filters`, that should be a `NSDictionary`, is an object of a different type.
So when the app stops at the exception breakpoint, please check the class of the instance `filters`.

Comment: I can't repro the crash... I am only getting in through BugSense from very few random crashes out of 1000's of users. I edited and added the stack trace to my original question.

Comment: The -count call could be coming from somewhere else. It would help to get a symbolicated backtrace (which would replace <redacted> with something more useful), and to know which line was line 2862.